# How can i implement payment through Paypal on Sharetribe opensource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, sharetribe

i'm trying to implement payment through Paypal on the opensource version of Sharetribe (https://github.com/sharetribe/sharetribe). By default Sharetribe doesn't allow people to use Paypal with the opensource code. How can i create the transaction using the Paypal API? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Checkout [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to properly as a question.

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question? What have you tried to use paypal so far. Is paypal not supported by sharetribe or are you only looking for the correct settings to use it?

Comment: I'm looking for the correct settings to use Paypal on my app

Comment: Your question is premature. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, and "[mcve]". We'd like to know what you tried: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/ helps as does http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharetribe doesn't have Paypal enabled on open source version because using Paypal as a peer-to-peer payment solution requires certain extra steps for a business to set up with Paypal.  Sharetribe has done this for their hosted websites, but can't be liable for open sourced versions.

The code is all there for Paypal, however most people are implementing [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/connect) instead, as, even with the Paypal code, Stripe Connect is a simpler solution to get your marketplace up and running.

In short, there is no 'setting' to turn on Paypal. A lot of code is required to enable payments.

If you want a marketplace ready-to-go with payments enabled, use Sharetribe's hosted version.  Otherwise, you'll need someone with solid knowledge of Ruby on Rails in order to implement Stripe Connect.